# A mutt macro to "mark as read" and archive simultaneously

Tags: macos, mutt

I've got mutt connected to Gmail imap

so far, I've got this:

```
macro index,pager y "<enter-command>unset trash\n <delete-message>" "Archive message"
```

But I can't figure out how it makes sure the message has been marked "read" before putting it away. The flow is like so: I'm in index view, then hit enter to read the message. I don't 'commit' that I've read this message with "$", but instead hit 'y' to archive. I would like to be able to combine the '$' mark as read or  while doing the archive (shown above)

Answer (score 4):

My mutt knowledge got a bit rusty (mainly using Gmail directly now), but I think you're looking to include `<clear-flag>N` in your macro, so you're sure that message is marked read before you do anything else. You also want something as `resolve=no` to avoid going to the next message.

This might work (untested):

```
macro index,pager y "<enter-command>unset resolve<enter><enter-command>unset trash<enter><clear-flag>N<enter-command>set resolve<enter><delete-message><enter>"
```